# Add specific hours in a specific time in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

Following is code that helps in adding specific hours in present time

```
date('H:i', strtotime('+1 hours'));
```

How should i add hours if the time and hours are dynamic. E.g I wish to add 2 hours to time 08:00, but these both things are saved in variables

> $hours = "2";
>
> $day_time = "08:00";

I tried the following but didn't work

```
$new_time = date($day_time, strtotime('+$hours hours'));
```

can anyone please tell how it can be done

Comment: @Cyclonecode tried not working, getting the error "A non well formed numeric value encountered "

Comment: Before going further with this code I suggest you use real timestamps instead of just hours. Humans are good with abstract stuff like hours but computers aren't. Use some type of year month date in all times and you will make it easier on yourself later in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime("+{$hours}hour ".$day_time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$h = 2 ;
$time="08:00";
$time = date('H:i', strtotime($time.'+'.$h.' hour'));
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$hours = 2;
$day_time = "08:00";
$new_time = date('H:i',strtotime($day_time."+$hours hours"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<?php
    $hours = "2";
    $day_time = "08:00";
    $new_time = date('H:i',strtotime($day_time.'+ '.$hours.' hour'));
    echo $new_time;
?>
```

> Output : 10:00

Answer (score 0):

Using datetime would be better to avoid

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

```
$date = new DateTime($day_time);
$date->modify("+".$hours." hours");
echo $date->format("H:i");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using a variable inside single quotes. There are some ways to fix this:

```
//awful and you should avoid it
//(hard to read, unsafe use of direct variables inside strings):
$new_time = date($day_time, strtotime("+$hours hours"));
```

or

```
//still awful and you should avoid it too:
$new_time = date($day_time, strtotime('+{$hours} hours'));
```

or

```
//a little better, but still unsafe:
$new_time = date($day_time, strtotime('+' . $hours . ' hours'));
```

or

```
//better, safe because it only adds numeric values to the hours:
$new_time = date($day_time, strtotime(sprintf('+%d hours', $hours)));
```

or

```
//the ideal solution, safer to use and more professional:
$dateObj = new DateTime();
$dateObj->modify(sprintf('+%d hours', $hours));
$new_time = $dateObj->format("H:i");
```

That's the beauty and the curse of PHP, you can always do things in more than one way.